# js + asp question

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a default.aspx page where there are a lot of menu links like:

```
<div class="leftMenuLink" onmouseover="changeClass(this, 'leftMenuLinkHover');" onmouseout="changeClass(this, 'leftMenuLink');" onclick="window.location='/alfa/33_75.htm'; return false;" classname="leftMenuLink">
<a href="/alfa/33_75.htm">33/75</a><br>
```

Well, the applicatios was not designed by me so I am now in the phase of reading and trying to run it locally..The problem is that when pressing the above url it says:

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

This flags to me that it should be a url rewrite and I can see one like that here:

```
<RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+).htm</LookFor>
    <SendTo>/DisplayModel.aspx?s=$1&amp;m=$2</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```

Well, I open DisplayModel page and trying to catch a debug on PageLoad but it never fires that...

Do you know why?

I have no other rewrite rule like that, neither htm static files so I'm just stucked to find what I am missing...

Thanks.

On production works great but locally not.
Any ideea?

Answer (score 0):

Strange..locally with IIS it works great. But directly from visual studio (Ctrl + f5) the url rewriting does not work...Maybe a guru can point out the problem.